# Numeric integration - singularity

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, interpolation

I have discrete data points of a function(I can have infinite number of points of the function), which is something like this:
[image]

I used trapezoidal function of Matlab for a numerical integration.

The problem is that increasing the number of points, does not reduce the error of the integration. As someone already answered, the problem lies on the spikes. But,

- why increasing the number of points does not decrease the error? Using 10k points or 10million points makes no difference.

Isn't really 10 million points enough to capture all details of this function?

Comment: No convergence after $10^6$ nodes sounds suspicious, can you share the algebraic form of the function?

Comment: If the number of points gets sufficiently high the error starts to increase again due to numerical roundoff. That said in this situation you would be better off with an adaptive method. The "integral" function in Matlab is adaptive, so that might help. If it doesn't, I can explain how to use Richardson extrapolation to devise an adaptive rule "from scratch".

Comment: By the way, if this is just a periodic function, as in your integral consists of the right half of a period, a period, and then the left half of a period (which is really what it looks like in the picture), then you may benefit from removing the two half periods and just doubling the value of the integral.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I also used the griddedInterpolant with spline and cubic method and then i used Integral and quadgk function of Matlab(with different rel and abs error). Interestingly, the error is pretty same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem with MATLAB before too, the problem lies in how it stores numbers. Theoretically the error would decrease but actually you are summing up more regions, each of which has a relatively increasing error. Here's an example:

---

Say I want to work out the derivative numerically at a given point, we have:
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
however, when making $h$ very small it will be fine if its a simple number (like $10^a)$ but when it has a large number of non-zero digits, matlab will store it rounded after the output, and so the value of $f(x+h)$ will not have the precision you want. Also, during the summation process there will be rounding after every addition.

---

Matlab by default uses 16 digits, however if you use the vpa function you can increase it, so you could write your own code for numerical integration that incorporates this, the number of digits vpa used can also be changed.

vpa    Variable precision arithmetic.
R = vpa(S) numerically evaluates each element of the double matrix
S using variable precision floating point arithmetic with D decimal
digit accuracy, where D is the current setting of DIGITS.
The resulting R is a SYM.

```
vpa(S,D) uses D digits, instead of the current setting of DIGITS.
D is an integer or the SYM representation of a number.

It is important to avoid the evaluation of an expression using double
precision floating point arithmetic before it is passed to vpa.
For example,
   phi = vpa((1+sqrt(5))/2)
first computes a 16-digit approximation to the golden ratio, then
converts that approximation to one with d digits, where d is the current
setting of DIGITS.  To get full precision, use symbolic arguments,
   phi = vpa((1+sqrt(sym(5)))/2)
or
   s = sqrt(sym(5))
   phi = vpa((1+s)/2)

Additional examples:
   vpa(pi,780) shows six consecutive 9's near digit 770 in the
      decimal expansion of pi.

   vpa(hilb(2),5) returns

      [    1., .50000]
      [.50000, .33333]

See also double, digits, subs.

Documentation for vpa
Other functions named vpa
```

You can recall this yourself using the command

```
help vpa
```

Comment: Thanks. Using sym and vpa slowed down the computation significantly and so far I could not see the difference in the result. It is somehow impossible to use more than 10k points, whereas i could use 10m points beforehand. Is it normal that it slows down 100 or 1000 times? or maybe i am doing some mistakes.  I used both Trapz function, and also I used griddedInterpolant and then Integral function of Matlab. Both of them failed.

Comment: @tio yeah that is normal, it has to store values differently (not my area of expertise double values are 64bit whereas vpa will store each known decimal as a cell in a vector instead, making each value take up more ram) Matlab has its limitations so the only other thought I have is to try and use other programs or research approximations for your function which may provide more accurate results